# Using pattern.compile for social security number

Tags: java, regex

We have a requirement that a social security number must be in the form 
"xxxx-xx-nnnn"  (x are literal and n represents a number, like a valid value is xxx-xx-5444.

I am trying to use Java Pattern and matcher.  So I do the following

```
String SSN_REGEXP = "xxx-xx-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";
...
assertTrue( "SSN " + ssn + " is not of format " + SSN_REGEXP, Pattern.compile(SSN_REGEXP).matcher(ssn).matches());
```

assertTrue will print the first argument if the second is false.  In this case, if pattern does not match.

I am getting this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: SSN  xxx-xx-5444 is not of format xxx-xx-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

as you can see, the SSN is "xxx-xx-5444".  So why is this failing?
I also tried the following:

```
"^xxx-xx-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"
"xxx\\-xx\\-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

in Java you have to double backslash I think because there are two levels of indirection and - said invalid escape.

So why is the regular expression not working?

Comment: x should be [a-zA-Z] or something

Comment: Are you sure that you send string like this "xxx-xx-5444"? I'm tryin' on my machine and this assertion in JUnit goes fine, without error. Looks like you have space character before xxx-xx.

Comment: It was correct.  I just had to do a ssn = ssn.trim();

Comment: or use "^[ \t]*xxx-xx-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][ \t]*$"

Comment: Just saw your comment @AlexanderPodkutin ;-)  100% correct

Answer (score 1):

The first char of `ssn` is actually a space:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: SSN  xxx-xx-5444 is not of format xxx-xx-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
                              ^
```

Your regex does not allow a space at this location. The best would be to trim your input string before validating it: `Pattern.compile(SSN_REGEXP).matcher(ssn.trim()).matches()`

Note that `matches()` matches the whole input string against the pattern. If you want to find a pattern within a string, you'll have to use `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a space at the beginning of the ssn. ssn is: `xxx-xx-5444`. But it should be `xxx-xx-5444`

When we inspect this part of the printed String: `SSN  xxx`, we can see there are two spaces there.